# Clear selected options of one react-select which depends on the other react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have two datasets in two react-selects.
E.g:

```
options2={
[value: 1, label:"apple",relationKey=1],
[value: 2, label:"orange",relationKey=2],
[value: 3, label:"banana",relationKey=2],
[value: 4, label:"pineapple",relationKey=2],
}

options1 ={
  [value: 1, label: "drink 1", relationKey=1],
  [value: 2, label: "drink 2", relationKey=2]
}
```

Now I have two react-selects where the second one depends on the values selected from the first one.

First select:

```
        <Select
        options={options1}
        placeholder="Choose..."
        isSearchable={true} 
        onChange={handleChange}
        isMulti
        />
```

Second select:

```
        <Select
        options={options2}
        placeholder="Choose..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        isMulti
        />
```

Now the scenario works all good transfering the selected value to one another, showing only the desired options and all that. So when I select `Drink 1` from the first select- it should only give me the options with `relationKey=1` and if I select `drink 2` it should list me the other options from option2 as well.
And this is working very well.

What I want to do is: when I select `Drink 1` and `Drink 2` and also select `apple, orange, banana, pineapple` from the second select, if I deselect Drink2, I should only have `apple` in the second select option list because `Drink1` is the only one selected.

I have tried with tons of if/else's but the datasets are dynamic and I cannot always know their relationKeys and their values...

Hope I was clear enough, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var options1 = [
      { "value": 1, "label": "drink 1", relationKey:1 },
      { "value": 2, "label": "drink 2", relationKey:2 },
    ];
    
    var options2 = [
      { "value": 1, "label": "apple", relationKey:1 },
      { "value": 2, "label": "orange", relationKey:2 },
      { "value": 3, "label": "banana", relationKey:2 },
      { "value": 4, "label": "pineapple", relationKey:2 },  
    ];

<ReactSelect options={options1} onChange={(e)=>{ 
                  // set your state here of parent
                }}/>
                  

                  <ReactSelect options={options2.filter(function (el) {
                    return el.relationKey === 'your parent selected id will be here';
                  })}/>
```